# Problems with Optionals

Tags: ios, swift, cell, viewdidload, for-in-loop

I started learning `Swift` on my own from books and a tutorial from YouTube. And when I tried to repeat over the video, I got the error

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`

In the cycle `for I in`

What is the problem here?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViwe: UICollectionView!
    
    var imagesUIImages = [UIImage]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionViwe.dataSource = self
        collectionViwe.delegate = self
        
        for i in 0...7 {
            let image = UIImage(named: "image \(i)")! 
            imagesUIImages.append(image)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you have started learning, it seems to be a good time for you to learn about optionals and force unwrapping in swift.

Comment: At what point does the loop fail? If it fails on the last repeat, then, @MacUserT is probably correct, that you only have 7 images. Otherwise, it could be that the image name is incorrect.

Comment: Hi alexandr, great that you expanded on the code, but this still doesn't help your problem. Apparently, you have in your assets catalogue images named "image 0" to "image 7". Can you show us where you have put these images?

Comment: I posted them in Assets

Comment: Where is that? I can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

As MacUserT suggests, you probably have 7 images instead of 8. I would like to add to his answer that it would be wise and a good practice to unwrap the optional first and if you have a value then it will be added to the list of images.

So the code would be,

```
for i in 0..<7 {
    if let image = UIImage(named: "image \(i)") {
        imagesUIImages.append(image)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have only seven images and not eight, but you count to eight. The range 0...7 counts to seven, including seven. If you only have seven images, you should count to six, for instance 0..<7 or 0...6.

If you indeed only have seven images, then the image "image 7" doesn't exist and, since you are force unwrapping it with an !, your app crashes.

Please, try:

```
for i in 0..<7 {
    let image = UIImage(named: "image \(i)")! 
    imagesUIImages.append(image)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't help (

Comment: Hi alexandr, then we need a bit more code to help you better.